# useContractCall in a loop from React

Tags: erc-721, react, frontend, typescript

I have created a smart contract where users can mint several ERC721 tokens.

I used the **ERC721Enumerable** extension from [OpenZeppelin](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#IERC721Enumerable) so I can easily retrieve which tokens have been minted by a specific address. From their documentation, this *Solidity* function returns the token ID at a specific index:

```
tokenOfOwnerByIndex(address owner, uint256 index) → uint256
```

I have no issue using the function in a loop with *Python* (I'm using Brownie for testing purpose):

```
balance = enumerable.balanceOf(account)
items = []
for i in range(0, balance):
   items.append(enumerable.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(account, i))
```

And I can even do the same with a React Front-end by using the following:

```
import { useContractFunction, useEthers, useContractCall } from "@usedapp/core"
```

```
const [tokenId]: any = useContractCall({
    abi: TimeCollectibleInterface,
    address: TimeCollectibleContractAddress,
    method: "tokenOfOwnerByIndex",
    args: [address, 0],
    }) ?? [];
```

The problem is that this hook only return one token ID the user has minted at a time. In this case it returns the token Id for "address" at position "0", as specified in the function args.

In my specific case, the user can mint up to 60 tokens (for instance: from tokenId=60 to 99 and from tokenId=110 to 119). My idea was thus to use this hooks in a loop (so looping from index=0 to index=balance of the user) but it seems it's not possible to use hooks together with loops in React.

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks I solved the issue by myself by using the *useCalls* function from useDapp instead of *useContractCall*.

First I get the number of ERC721 tokens the user has in his balance :

```
    const [userBalance]: any = useContractCall({
        abi: TimeCollectibleInterface,
        address: TimeCollectibleContractAddress,
        method: "balanceOf",
        args: [address],
        }) ?? [0];

    var balanceItems = Array.from(Array(Number(userBalance)).keys())
```

I then use the useCalls to call each item at a time :

```
    const results = useCalls(
        userBalance
          ? balanceItems.map((idx: any) => ({
              contract: new Contract(TimeCollectibleContractAddress, TimeCollectibleInterface),
              method: 'tokenOfOwnerByIndex',
              args: [userAddress, idx],
            }))
          : []
      )
```

This ends up by returning an [object object] with the different items owned by the user. Might not be the best looking solution, but at least it works!